# How can I use static members in friend functions without prefixing [class name]::

Tags: c++, class, static, namespaces, friend

I have this code in `Player.h`

```
class Player {
  friend void clearBoard();

private:
  static char board[4][4][4];
};
```

and this code in `Player.cpp`

```
char Player::board[4][4][4] = {};

void
clearBoard() {
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (byte j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      for (byte k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        board[i][j][k] = ' ';
}
```

so during compilation I get an error

```
Player.cpp:37:9: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope
   37 |         board[i][j][k] = ' ';
      |         ^~~~~
```

I use `board` literally hundred other times in the `Player.cpp` and using `Player::` with each one will negatively affect readability an my nerves.

Is there a way to escape this hell?

I have tried

1. `using Player::board;`
2. `using Player::board[][][];`
3. Enclosing my class with namespace, then using that
   namespace.

without any effect.

- - 

*All suggestions except*

> "*just redefine `clearBoard()` as `static`*"

*will be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: "using `Player::` with each one will negatively affect readability" -- no, it won't. Just do it.

Comment: I have board[i][j][k] in if statements. A lot of them...

Comment: <shrug></shrug>

Comment: if a name of a variable is too long you can always do `auto& x = some_super_long_variable_name;`. Though, typing less != readability. There is a reason you need to qualify where a name comes from

Comment: you can use `inline` for `static` members with `c++17` instead of explicit initialization. outside the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general typing less is not a way to improve readability. Writing `Player::board` is good because if you write `board` outside of `Player` then it is not clear where it comes from. Having said this, you can always introduce an alias if a variable name is too long and you are too lazy to type its name repeadetely:

```
void
clearBoard() {
  auto& board = Player::board;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (byte j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      for (byte k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        board[i][j][k] = ' ';
}
```

Just make sure to keep the scope of the alias short and in this specific example I fail to see the benefit (introducing the alias is more typing, not less).

Comment: https://github.com/zzaba/3D_Tic-Tac-Toe/blob/master/Player.cpp
Here, in status() I use board 84 times.

Comment: @beardeadclown and? Writing `Player::` 84 times makes it obvious at a blink that those 84 `board`s come from `Player`

Comment: Can you recommend any books/guidelines for good coding practices like that?

Comment: @beardeadclown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list and https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines